# What is my friend trying to tell me?

Tags: cipher

My friend sent me the following short message:

> D57919749C3641B796384D0795DDE33739ED3E03

How should I decode it?

Hint:

> My friend's job is writing software for mobile phones.

Hint2:

> The original message was 22 characters long.

Hint 3:

> It is relevant that it was a Short Message that my friend sent me.

Comment: Almost looks like a SHA1 hash....

Comment: Clearly, this is simple hex and your friend is trying to tell you "Õytœ6A·–8M•Ýã79í>�"

Comment: @Tryth, good thought but it's not a hash.

Comment: Something to do with mobile phone keypads?

Comment: Nope,. not to do with the keypad.

Comment: @mmking if it is AES we will have a good time brute-forcing keys... :D

Comment: @BojidarMarinov That's what I was worried about.

Comment: The original message was 22 characters long, but this one is 40?

Comment: @Raystafarian, yes, that is correct.

Comment: It is not AES or any form of "computer encryption" as normally understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend sent you text in the form of the 7-bit GSM Alphabet, which is how the text in an SMS message is stored. When [decoded](http://www.twit88.com/home/utility/sms-pdu-encode-decode), the text will be:

> Use GSM 7-bit encoding

Answer (score 2):

Decoded it is - `Use GSM 7-bit encoding`

This is the USSD GSM 7bit packed encoding.

I used [this tool](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288). Given the original message was 22 characters (above answer) we need to convert the long-form from the question (40 characters) to the SMS (short message service) text.